# MS Bookings Graph API send to multiple participants

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

We have been extensively using graph API's and Bookings and have a request for scheduling group sessions through Bookings. Currently, we think we can only do this by recursively generating a booking for each person. We would like to be able to specify a list in the JSON when creating it.

Use Case is for a group therapy session that will have multiple people.

Part two of the request is to be able to publish a booking event and allow multiple external users to sign up to attend.

All tips and guidance welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I would try this: (1) Create an Azure AD based application and choose the Identity flow suits you (2) Get the access token from Azure AD (3) With the token make Graph API calls (Bookings/Calendar) based on your application logic and send to multiple participants... In addition, even you can think about considering Azure A2C scenario as well, so that you can allow multiple external users to sign up to attend.

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: Hi - Thanks for checking in. We have been trying the BETA version of the Bookings graph API Batch calls and that seems to be working

Comment: Glad to hear that its working. I will move this to answer - so it can be useful to others; you can consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an Azure AD based application and choose the Identity flow suits you
- Get the access token from Azure AD
- With the token make Graph API calls (Bookings/Calendar) based on your application logic and send to multiple participants...
- In addition, even you can think about considering Azure A2C scenario as well, so that you can allow multiple external users to sign up to attend.
- You confirmed that you're trying the BETA version of the Bookings graph API Batch calls
  and that seems to be working.